# validating currency in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate currency with the following function:

```
function checkwages(input){
    var validformat=/^\d{0,5}(\.\d{1,2})?$/;
    if ( validformat.test(input)) {
        // alert("$:"+ input + " test");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The goal is to make sure user enters either numbers or decimal format. It cannot be 0 or negative. However when the input field is blank this fails as 0 digits is valid in this format. However, if I change it to `/^\d{1,5}(\.\d{1,2})?$/` then .21 becomes invalid and forces user to enter something like 0.21. How can I change the regex so that even .21 is considered valid number?

Thanks

Comment: Do JavaScript regexes accept look-aheads? If not, you cannot do it with one regex only.

Comment: There is a way to modify the regex to consider this OR that, I just couldn't find the right way of doing it. All my trials failed some way or the other.. But I am pretty sure there is a way of doing it with one regex

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Anyway, so if I understand correctly, you want it to accept a number without decimal point (e.g. 2345), with decimal point (234.56) but also .XX, correct?

Comment: I don't think you can do it without look-aheads.

Comment: And who said JS can't do lookaheads?  :)

Comment: cwolves gave you a regex with look-aheads below. @cwolves: I didn't say anything, I just don't know JS and was asking ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^(?=.*[1-9])\d{0,5}(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

the bit at the beginning looks for a non-zero anywhere in the string, but doesn't capture it.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to prove with RegEx that the input is bigger than 0. But this is one of your conditions ("It cannot be 0"). So even with your second RegEx the user could enter 0 or 0.0 and this would be evaluated to true.

My suggestion is that you use your first RegEx and combine it with this simple comparison:

```
if ( validformat.test(input) && input.length > 0 && input > 0)
```

Then the validation should meet all your requirements and it's very simple (dynamic typing ftw).

Comment: Nope, won't work. Read his question again, he explains why ;)

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about the blank input. But that's not really a problem. Just add "input.length > 0" and it will work. I have edited my answer so that it should be correct now.

Comment: by the way '' > 0 returns false. So the input.length > 0 isn't necessary.